# Running 'cd' command in my npm script

Tags: unix, npm, cd, npm-scripts

I would like to run an npm script that contains `cd folderName/` or `cd ../www/folderName/` but it seems that npm is unable to run the `cd` command nor is it able to run the `cp` command (i installed cpx which seems to work well with it).

Any solution for a script that npm will run that allows me to change directories?

Thanks!

Update:

Ok this is one of the npm scripts that I need `cd` for ..

```
"buildWWW": "babel-node tools/build.js && cpx 'dist/*.{js,map,css,ico}' '../www/public' && cd ../www/ && node app.js"
```

replacing `cd ../www/ && node app.js` with `node ../www/app.js` is not an option.

Update #2: Simple test case

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDS4c.jpg

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: `cd` works in npm-scripts here on Windows and macOS. Which OS are you running (Linux?) and what version of npm?

Comment: I'm on macOS, running npm v 5.6.0. So if I try a basic command such as "test": "cd /dist", it will run and do nothing; thus I assume it does nothing. can someone else reproduce this? See the images posted in Update #2

Comment: Given the scenario shown in your screenshot - that’s normal behaviour, i.e. when the npm-script  named `test` exits, the `pwd` reported will be tthe same as when you initially run `npm run test`. It simply returns back to the directory you started at. However, that test case, doesn’t represent your initial question. It should `cd` to `../www` and then run `node app.js` as per your `buildWWW` script example though.

Comment: @RobC I agree with both your points yes. my node js command does not execute though :(. thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's certainly odd. To check it's not a file permissions issue: Does running `node ../www/app.js` via the command line invoke the script? The only other thing worth a try, _(although not a normal a requirement of npm-scripts)_, is to make the script executable by running `chmod u+x ../www/app.js`, then try `npm run buildWWW`. Good luck!